# URL Rewriting in Lightning to support Classic functionality

Tags: visualforce, lightning, encoding, url-encode

I have an Apex logic that checks: On click of New button of Opportunity, if the logged-in user has permission to create records, reconstruct the PageReference with the default url like below:

```
https://myinstance.my.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F006%3Ffcf%3D00Ba0000009uqqV&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=VmpFPSxNakF4Tnkwd015MHlOMVF4TURveU5Eb3hNeTQzT1RSYSxiTm9LeV9XdEpKQVMtRUdzb3pHUVdZLE0yUTJPVFJs&common.udd.actions.ActionsUtilORIG_URI=%2F006%2Fe&RecordType=01230000000rrnN&ent=Opportunity
```

If I do it in Lightning I am able to redirect to land on new record opportunity page but I am getting an error: [image]

I know this is related to constructing the same using the URLEncoding appending in Aloha url

```
/one/one.app?source=aloha#/sObject/[recordId]/view?fv0={!Object__c.field}
```

But I am not able to figure out, how should I make and which part of the url has to be encoded. Please suggest.

Comment: Looks like a permission error.. Make sure your profiles have access to the record type listed in the URL (01230000000rrnN).

Comment: I think the record type id is not getting passed. as its working fine in classic. And the record type assignment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning data service (though still in developer preview and super involved) is meant to solve this

[Loading a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not asking in context of Lightning Components. I know it can be done via Visualforce without having the lightning tags involved anywhere. Please suggest.

Comment: Can we develop a Lightning component to call the Visualforce which will perform the same task I want on click of "New" standard Button?